# Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/.. .. func=processForm' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: file, google-apps-script, upload, x-frame-options

I am trying to upload a file to my Google drive.

On the server side I have this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


function processForm( form ) 
{

}
```

This is the HTML with the client side javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<h1>Upload test</h1>
<form >
File1 <input type="file"  name="file1" id="file1" >   <br> 
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="pre_submit_check( this.parentNode )" >   
<div id='message'>
</div>
</form>


  </body>
<script>
function pre_submit_check( thisForm )
{
      google.script.run
      .processForm( thisForm );           

}</script>
```

According to [the entry for google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) I should be able to pass the form from the client side to the server side but doing so generates this error "Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/.. .. func=processForm' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

The behavior is the same when I use setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL); whcih from what I have read should get round this restriction.

This is the console.log from the client side

> userCodeAppPanel:1 Refused to display
>   'https://script.google.com/a/macros/sjsu.edu/s/AKfycbwgUQIH3Oh78HrrhjultwKLuqSf7s1fkX7QCF4W6EA/postform?nocache_id=1&token=AJuLMu3zKyGB1DMff2VLg1MxcBMWKZFbLQ%3A1503682662444&fsid=1da35034-7a52-4a9d-a5ec-a125f4f9b771&func=processForm'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:77 POST
>   https://script.google.com/a/macros/sjsu.edu/s/AKfycbwgUQIH3Oh78HrrhjultwKLuqSf7s1fkX7QCF4W6EA/postform?nocache_id=1&token=AJuLMu3zKyGB1DMff2VLg1MxcBMWKZFbLQ%3A1503682662444&fsid=1da35034-7a52-4a9d-a5ec-a125f4f9b771&func=processForm
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE Sf.i @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:77 Ve.h @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:56 t.ga @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:52 gg.J @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:86 md @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:30 id @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:31 (anonymous) @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:28 postMessage
>   (async) Ti.f @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:153 ve @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:70 Ni @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:150 (anonymous)
>   @ 3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:19 v.wa @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:145 Od @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:60 T @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:58 yg @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:85 Wh.j @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:133 Od @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:60 T @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:58 Fh @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:119 v.Pa @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:118 v.ya @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:118
>   XMLHttpRequest.send (async) v.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:116 Wh.ua @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:132 wg.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:85 v.Za @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:143 v.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:142 $h.D @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:137 Mi.f @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:149 je.c @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:66 Ui @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:153 Ti.j @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:152 postMessage
>   (async) Qe @ 1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:85
>   t.la @ 1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:50
>   (anonymous) @ 1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:6
>   (anonymous) @ 1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:40
>   pre_submit_check @ userCodeAppPanel:7 onclick @ userCodeAppPanel:1
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:116 GET
>   https://script.google.com/a/macros/sjsu.edu/s/AKfycbwgUQIH3Oh78HrrhjultwKLuqSf7s1fkX7QCF4W6EA/postresponse?nocache_id=3&fsid=1da35034-7a52-4a9d-a5ec-a125f4f9b771&token=AJuLMu3zKyGB1DMff2VLg1MxcBMWKZFbLQ%3A1503682662444 500 () v.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:116 Wh.ua @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:132 wg.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:85 v.Za @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:143 v.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:142 $h.D @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:137 Mi.f @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:149 je.c @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:66 Ui @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:153 Ti.j @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:152 postMessage
>   (async) Qe @ 1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:85
>   t.fa @ 1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:53 Tf @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:83 (anonymous) @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:6 md @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:30 id @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:31 (anonymous) @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:28
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:49 Uncaught
>   NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 500 g @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:49 Oe @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:55 (anonymous) @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:6 gg.J @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:86 md @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:30 id @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:31 (anonymous) @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:28 postMessage
>   (async) Ti.l @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:154 ve @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:70 Oi @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:150 (anonymous)
>   @ 3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:19 v.wa @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:146 Od @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:60 T @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:58 yg @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:85 Wh.j @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:133 Od @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:60 T @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:58 Dh @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:117 Fh @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:119 v.Pa @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:118 v.ya @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:118
>   XMLHttpRequest.send (async) v.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:116 Wh.ua @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:132 wg.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:85 v.Za @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:143 v.send @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:142 $h.D @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:137 Mi.f @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:149 je.c @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:66 Ui @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:153 Ti.j @
>   3189932465-mae_html_driver_bin_i18n_mae_html_driver.js:152 postMessage
>   (async) Qe @ 1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:85
>   t.fa @ 1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:53 Tf @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:83 (anonymous) @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:6 md @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:30 id @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:31 (anonymous) @
>   1484611146-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:28

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try deploying it again as a web app, I've tried your code and didn't encounter any issues. What errors did you encounter?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added the console.log to the original post.

Comment: @SimonRodan did you find the solution for this?